# Can accelerating magnets create electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

We know accelerating charges create changing electric field and those changing electric fields generate magnetic fields. Now as the electric field is changing, so the magnetic field it generates also changes which in turn generates electric field and the process continues and the wave propagates in all directions. Similarly a accelerating magnet will create changing magnetic field and that changing magnetic field will generate changing electric field and that will in turn generate magnetic field and the process will continue. So can moving magnets actually create electromagnetic waves?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is the working principle of Power Generators, which is based on Faraday's Law of Induction.

Note that, **moving charges does NOT produce EM radiation** only ACCELERATING charge produce radiation, similarly, accelerating magnet will also produce radiation. Although it should be noted that unlike charge which comes in monopoles, a magnet comes in dipoles. Hence the em radiation of accelerating magnets is pretty weird.

Comment: Sorry I meant acceleration , thanks for your correction and your explanation was also great

Comment: It's usual to tick or upvote an answer that you think is great, there are a few today where you could have done that...

Comment: So, every kind of light or electromagnetic radiation should cause an alternating current in a conductor.(note that I am not talking about photoelectric effect).

Comment: In principle it can produce a local AC effect at the location where the EM radiation interacts with matter (it does lead to oscillating electrons). But it doesn't lead to an AC current moving across the conductor, mainly because there are other more dominant phenomena that happen at microscopic scales.